# jquery ui slider jumping to next step on slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a jQuery UI slider to which is set in months but has a step value of 12 months.

```
  $( "#slider_months" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: 48,
  min: 12,
  max: 60,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#header_months" ).html( ui.value );
  },
```

However what I am finding is that if the user moves the slider a little way to the left or right it doesn't move at all but if i move it a long way it jumps to the next interval. For example I couldn't move from 12 months to 14 months - the drag bar just doesn't respond. But if I tried to drag if from 12 months to 20 months the drag bar will automatically jump to the nearest step of 24 months.

What I would like the slider to do is always move and not 'get stuck' and jump automatically to the next step even if you try and move the bar just a little.

Here is a jfiddle of the slider
http://jsfiddle.net/andieje/uHuD7/

Here is the code

```
$(function() {
      $( "#slider_months" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 48,
      min: 12,
      max: 60,
      step: 12,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#header_months" ).html( ui.value );
      },
      change: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "#header_months" ).html( ui.value );
       }
    });
```

Comment: What should happen if someone stops on say 30 which is halfway between 24 and 36?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have `step: 12,`. It won't move in little increments if you set a step that is equal to a fifth of the slider. (Just think about it.)

If you want to it to be more responsive, you need to work in [smaller steps](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/uHuD7/2/):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider_months" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 48,
        min: 12,
        max: 60,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#header_months" ).html( ui.value );
        },
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#header_months" ).html( ui.value );
        }
    });
});
```

I don't understand the point of doing it in steps of 12 months. Why don't you just do it in years? That way you can have small steps of 1 year…

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that lets you drag for all values between 0 and 60 and when you stop dragging it will snap to an increment of 12. For values exactly between two multiple of 12 (e.g. 30) it will round up but you can easily change that.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uHuD7/3/)**

```
$("#slider_months").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 48,
    min: 12,
    max: 60,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#header_months").html(ui.value);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#header_months").html(ui.value);
        var mod = ui.value % 12;
        if (mod != 0) {
            if (mod < 6) {
                $("#slider_months").slider({
                    value: Math.floor(ui.value / 12) * 12
                });

            } else if (mod >= 6) {
                $("#slider_months").slider({
                    value: Math.ceil(ui.value / 12) * 12
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```